# Xamarin Shell tabbar color changes on iOS when there is content behind it

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Shell Tabbar with a custom renderer and a Collection view that goes behind it.
Now when there is content in my Collection view that is behind the tabbar, the tabbar background color whitens.

before
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiXVt.png)
after
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1VMj.png)

I tried turning my custom renderer off and it worked as expected and there are no color changes, so I know that it is in my custom renderer but I can't figure out what it is.

Custom Renderer:

```
public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection)
    {
        var renderer = base.CreateShellSectionRenderer(shellSection);
        if (renderer != null)
        {
        }
        return renderer;
    }
    protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        return new CustomTabbarAppearance();
    }

}
public class CustomTabbarAppearance : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller)
    {
    }

    public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        UITabBar myTabBar = controller.TabBar;
        UIColor tabBarColor = ((Xamarin.Forms.Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["MyTabBarColor"]).ToUIColor();

        if (myTabBar != null)
        {
            UIView view = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, myTabBar.Frame.Width, 2)) { BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(17, 17, 17).ToUIColor() };
            myTabBar.AddSubview(view);

            myTabBar.BackgroundColor = tabBarColor;//change
            myTabBar.BarTintColor = tabBarColor;

            myTabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.White;

            if (myTabBar.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (UITabBarItem item in myTabBar.Items)
                {
                    item.Title = null;
                    item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(10, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds like the tabbar background color has some transparency. Test with hardcoded background color directly in the custom renderer, to see if you can get the symptom to stop.

Comment: I already have the background color set directly in the custom renderer.
But noticed that when i remove the bartintcolor it gets brighter so I think it has something to do with that.

Comment: There does seemt to be some interaction between those two. google `xamarin ios bartintcolor vs background color`. Lots of discussion - I don't know if any of those "solve" it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved it, the hint with the transparency was right it just wasn't the transparency of the color, my tabbar was somehow set to translucent

my working code:

```
UIView myView = null;
    public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        UITabBar myTabBar = controller.TabBar;
        UIColor tabBarColor = ((Xamarin.Forms.Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["MyTabBarColor"]).ToUIColor();

        if (myTabBar != null)
        {
            myView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, myTabBar.Frame.Width, 2)) { BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(17, 17, 17).ToUIColor() };
            myTabBar.AddSubview(myView);

            myTabBar.BackgroundColor = tabBarColor;
            myTabBar.BarTintColor = tabBarColor;
            myTabBar.Translucent = false;

            myTabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.White;

            if (myTabBar.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (UITabBarItem item in myTabBar.Items)
                {
                    item.Title = null;
                    item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(10, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to hard-code `tabBarColor` in your code , and update `Xamarin.Forms` to the latest .

[image]

---

What's more , there is a small suggestion to your code .

`SetAppearance` method calls while switching the `Tabbar`,so it keeps adding the  view  .

It is supposed to add the view only once ,it's better to change the logic .

#### Update

```
UIView myView = null;
public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
{
    UITabBar myTabBar = controller.TabBar;
    UIColor tabBarColor = UIColor.White;  //to any color you want

    if (myTabBar != null)
    {
       if (myView != null) return;

       myView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, myTabBar.Frame.Width, 2)) { BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(17, 17, 17).ToUIColor() };
               
       myTabBar.AddSubview(myView);

       myTabBar.BackgroundColor = tabBarColor;//change
       myTabBar.BarTintColor = tabBarColor;

       myTabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.White;

       if (myTabBar.Items != null)
       {
           foreach (UITabBarItem item in myTabBar.Items)
           {
               item.Title = null;
               item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(10, 0, 0, 0);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, could you provide me with the code where you hardcoded the color and do you have any hint on how to change my logic?

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: sadly once I change the color from white to black it still has the issue.