# AppShell tabbar color changes on iOS when there is content behind it

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, uitabbar, app-shell

I have the exact same issue as asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70512358/xamarin-shell-tabbar-color-changes-on-ios-when-there-is-content-behind-it). The tabbar changes color when there is content behind it. However, as stated in this question, if they remove the renderer then their problem stops. I currently do not have a renderer at all and still have this problem. The only part of my code that doesn't have this problem are pages that are not in the shell hierarchy and that are navigated to using the following line of code:

```
var search = new SearchList();
Navigation.PushAsync(search);
```

The pages that are navigated to using the style of the following lines of code have the tabbar issue:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MemberList)}");
```

The xaml and code behind for the different pages are the exact same. The only difference is one is defined in the appshell hierarchy(MemberList) and the other is not(SearchList) as seen below:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleYE.Views"
       Title="SampleYE"
       x:Class="SampleYE.AppShell"
      >

    <!--
        The overall app visual hierarchy is defined here, along with navigation.
    
        https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/
    -->

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#AD94BB" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="{StaticResource Tertiary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="{StaticResource Tertiary}"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>

    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="StartupPage" Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:StartupPage}" />
    </TabBar>

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Directory" Icon="icon_feed.png">
            <ShellContent  Route="MemberList" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MemberList}"/>
        </Tab> 
        <Tab Title="Profile" Icon="icon_about.png">
            <ShellContent Route="ProfilePage1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ProfilePage1}" />
        </Tab>                  
    </TabBar>

    <!--
        If you would like to navigate to this content you can do so by calling
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
    -->
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="LoginPage1" Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage1}" />
    </TabBar>


</Shell>
```

The definition of the pages with the issue are as follows:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="SampleYE.Views.MemberList">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" IsGroupingEnabled="true">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image WidthRequest="44" HeightRequest="44" Source="{Binding Photo}" />
                            <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Font="Medium" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Font="Micro" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto">

                <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" >
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*,*" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            RowSpacing="25">
                            <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"
                                    CornerRadius="75" HasShadow="False" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                <Image Source="Profile" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                                HeightRequest="54" WidthRequest="54" CornerRadius="27" TranslationX="65"
                                ImageSource="Camera" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                
                            <Frame Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsClippedToBounds="True"
                                Margin="20,20,20,0" CornerRadius="15" Padding="0,20,0,20"    >
                                <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*" RowSpacing="12" ColumnSpacing="5">
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            Text="Calvin"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            Text="Carter"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                          Text="Ace"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="Wrecking Ball"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            Text="Spring"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            Text="2014"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                 
                            <Frame Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsClippedToBounds="False"
                                    Margin="20,20,20,0" CornerRadius="15" Padding="0,20,0,45" >
                                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto,Auto,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*" RowSpacing="20" ColumnSpacing="5" >
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                             Text="02/01/1994"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                             Text="Wreckingball14"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                             Text="CCC@blackhousedevelopers.com"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                 Text="Wrecking Ball"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                              Text="Spring"/>
                                         <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                              Text="2014"/>
                                     </Grid>
                             </Frame>
                  
                            <Grid
                                 Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsClippedToBounds="False"
                                Margin="20,0,20,0"  Padding="0,20,0,20"
                                    RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*,*" RowSpacing="20" >
                        
                                <Frame IsClippedToBounds="true" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                           Padding="0"
                                         CornerRadius="15">
                                      <Editor HeightRequest="70" x:Name="interestEntry"
                                              BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" TextColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                                             Placeholder="Interests (i.e. UFC, Fishing, Investing etc;)"
                                             PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>

                                </Frame >
                
                                <Frame IsClippedToBounds="true" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     Padding="0"
                                     CornerRadius="15">
                                    <Editor  HeightRequest="140" x:Name="bioEntry" 
                                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" TextColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                                       Placeholder="Biography (A little information about yourself)"
                                       PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
                                </Frame>
                        
                            </Grid>
                
                    </Grid>

            
                </ScrollView>
        
                
          
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: How have you defined `LoginPage1`, such that its content extends behind tabbar? I thought a page normally stopped before the tabbar. Maybe put `Grid RowDefinitions="*" />` as outermost layout. Unless X-Forms does something peculiar, that should fill the area above tabbar only. (But be aware that RelativeLayout or AbsoluteLayout would ignore that limitation, so shouldn't be used in this situation.)

Comment: LoginPage1 does not have the issue. MemberList and ProfilePage1 have the issue. The definition for those pages were added to the original post.

Comment: After `<ContentPage.Content>`, Instead of `<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto">`, try `<Grid RowDefinitions="*">`. That is supposed to fill the available space; should not extend below tabbar. (Auto "shouldn't" either, but sounds like it is buggy on iOS. `"*"` has a simpler, hopefully more reliable, height calculation.)

Comment: I have just attempted this and it doesn't work. It also wouldn't explain why the listview on the MemberList page is causing the same issue that without the defined defined grid behavior @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas. Details: *"It also wouldn't explain why the listview on the MemberList page is causing the same issue"* - I understand there is a bug on iOS. I am trying to find an approach that avoids the bug - I was hoping that an explicit `Grid *` would work. If it did, then the solution would be to wrap all pages' content with that. Now that you've tested that, I conclude that it isn't a layout problem, so can't be fixed by using a different layout. It seems iOS + Shell + TabBar incorrectly believes the "content" height includes the area behind it. No easy work-around.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this was updating my ios project to a newer version. they fixed it in the update.

Comment: You can add more details to your post and mark it as an answer as it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).